# How can one connect to remote hypertable in python

Tags: hypertable, mesos

I'm trying to connect to a hypertable master machine, hypertable is deployed via mesos, When I copy hypertable.cfg file from master machine to some arbitrary machine, after running start-thriftbroker.sh, all I get is about ten lines of "Waiting for ThriftBroker to come up..." and then "ERROR: ThriftBroker did not come up", ThirftBroker's logfile says:

```
1342340080 NOTICE ThriftBroker : (/root/src/hypertable/src/cc/Common/Config.cc:526) Initializing ThriftBroker (Hypertable 0.9.5.6 (v0.9.5.6-dirty))...
CPU cores count=1
CephBroker.MonAddr=10.0.1.245:6789
CephBroker.Port=38030
CephBroker.Workers=20
DfsBroker.Host=localhost
DfsBroker.Local.Port=38030
DfsBroker.Local.Root=fs/local
DfsBroker.Port=38030
HdfsBroker.Port=38030
HdfsBroker.Workers=20
HdfsBroker.fs.default.name=hdfs://<ip>:9010
Hyperspace.GracePeriod=200000
Hyperspace.KeepAlive.Interval=30000
Hyperspace.Lease.Interval=1000000
Hyperspace.Replica.Dir=hyperspace
Hyperspace.Replica.Host=[<ip>]
Hyperspace.Replica.Port=38040
Hyperspace.Replica.Workers=20
Hypertable.Master.Port=38050
Hypertable.Master.Workers=20
Hypertable.RangeServer.Port=38060
Hypertable.Verbose=true
ThriftBroker.Port=38080
pidfile=/opt/hypertable/current/run/ThriftBroker.pid
port=38080
reactors=1
verbose=true
1342340080 INFO ThriftBroker : (/root/src/hypertable/src/cc/Hyperspace/Session.cc:63) Hyperspace session setup to reconnect
1342340082 ERROR ThriftBroker : main (/root/src/hypertable/src/cc/ThriftBroker/ThriftBroker.cc:2404): Hypertable::Exception: Hyperspace 'mkdir' error, name=/hypertable/namemap/names - HYPERSPACE file exists
        at void Hyperspace::Session::mkdir(const std::string&, bool, const std::vector<Hyperspace::Attribute, std::allocator<Hyperspace::Attribute> >*, Hypertable::Timer*) (/root/src/hypertable/src/cc/Hyperspace/Session.cc:1257)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got solved by updating to new version of ht.

Comment: Can you accept this answer since the new version of HT fixed your problem?